# Do I need to declare a unique constraint for `bigint generated always as identity`?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, multi-tenant

I'm creating a multi-tenant application and am prepending the `tenant_id` to all tables that my tenants will access. All of the tables will also have an incrementing surrogate key. Will I need to declare a unique constraint of the surrogate key or is that redundant?

```sql
CREATE TABLE tenant (
  primary key (tenant_id),
  tenant_id  bigint generated always as identity
);

CREATE TABLE person (
  primary key (tenant_id, person_id)
  person_id  bigint generated always as identity,
  tenant_id  bigint not null,

  unique (person_id),  -- Do I need this?

  foreign key (tenant_id) references tenant
);
```

Comment: `person_id` should be the primary key in the table `person`.

Comment: You must declare the constraint. While the "as identity' would seem to indicate as a key or unique column it does not. It only indicates It only indicates how the field is built and some restrictions on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key of a table should be a minimal set of columns that uniquely identify a table row. So that should be `person_id`, as it was specifically created for that purpose.

Add another (non-unique) index on `tenant_id` or `(tenant_id, person_id)` if you need to speed up searches based on `tenant_id`.